# C++ Could not convert vector pair

Tags: c++, vector

Can anyone tell me why the function edge is returning:

```
error: could not convert ‘g’ from ‘std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > [(grafo::n + 1)]’ to ‘std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >’
   30 |         return g;
      |                ^
      |                |
      |                std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > [(grafo::n + 1)]
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class grafo
{
public:
    static int n, e;
    grafo(int n, int e)
    {
        this->e = e;
        
        int u, v, w;
        for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
        {
            cin >> u;
            cin >> v;
            cin >> w;
            edges(u, v, w);
        }
        //dijkstra(n, g);
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > edges(int u, int v, int w){
        this->n = n;
        vector<pair<int, int>> g[n+1]; // lista de adjacencia
        g[u].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
        g[v].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
        return g;
     }

    void dijkstra(int n){
        //g.
    }

};

int main()
{
    int n, e, src;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> e;
    grafo g(n,e);
    
    // dijkstra(n, g, src);
}
```

Comment: Double check `vector<pair<int, int>> g[n+1];`.  What is the type of `g`?  Does that match the return type that you specified in `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > edges(int u, int v, int w)`?

Comment: change to `vector<pair<int, int>> g(n+1)`, otherwise you are making an array

Comment: you're trying to return an `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > ` but you create an array of vectors

Comment: @Claudemir Macêdo What is the sense of this assignment this->n = n; within the function edges?! It is the same as to write this->n = this->n; or n = n;

Comment: `vector<pair<int, int>> g[n+1];` You do **not** want to use square brackets here with `[n+1]`.  This is a typo (that results in something that is not standard C++, but looks like a dynamically sized array supported by some compilers).  I think you intended to either resize or reserve n+1 elements in the vector.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Also the 2 static variabes declared with `static int n, e;` are fishy. You most likely don't want static class variables here.

Answer (score 2):

Below I will explain what looks wrong in your code:

1. In line:

   ```
   static int n, e;
   ```

you state that `n` and `e` should be `static` this makes those variable to be available to each instance of `grafo`. I doubt this is you intent. You probably wanted each instance of `grafo` to have its own values for those variables:

```
   int n, e;
```

2. Here:

   ```
   grafo(int n, int e)
   {
    this->e = e;
   ```

you assign new value to `this->e`. It looks ok, but more descriptive would be to give good names to variables like:

```
int nodes, edges;
grafo(int nodes_to_read, int edges_to_read)
{
    edges = edges_to_read;
```

3. Here:

   ```
   std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > edges(int u, int v, int w){
    this->n = n;
    vector<pair<int, int>> g[n+1]; // lista de adjacencia
    g[u].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
    g[v].push_back(make_pair(v,w));
    return g;
   }
   ```

line `this->n = n;` makes no sense. Line `vector<pair<int, int>> g[n+1];` indicates you want to create an array on stack of `vector<pair<int, int>>` type which is currently forbidden in c++ and should actually give you an error. What you probably meant here is to create a `vector` and add edges to it:

```
    vector<pair<int, int>> g; // lista de adjacencia
    g.push_back(make_pair(v,w));
    g.push_back(make_pair(v,w));
```

read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for `std::vector`, and how it works.